# Print MySQL table in PHP without knowing the columns

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently making a private "list management" system in which I store SQL queries in the database. So that I can via the front-end create new "lists" (which basicly are sql queries), and view them.

I have made the front end so you can save queries into the database, and im at the point where I want PHP execute and print out the results of one of my queries. This happens when I select one of my stored "lists" on my frontend. So when I press one of the lists, it should execute the SQL query. So far, so good.

But how can I, via PHP, print a table (like the one you get out from phpMyAdmin when viewing the contents of a table) without knowing how many / what columns exists? I want the script to be dynamic, so I can view results of all kinds of SELECT queries (on different tables).

Any tips or pointers?

Comment: you can show this with the array index with mysql_fetch_array funcion

Comment: what about `SELECT * FROM TABLE` ?

Comment: Hi John, I know - But how can I create a HTML table which the first row contains all the column names and then one row for each of the entries? Without specifying in the script f.instance <tr><td>$row[customer_name]</td><td>$row[phonenr]</td></tr>

Comment: @HalayemAnis yes, thats the query I would use. But how can I then print that out via PHP in a decent looking <table>?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rather than using deprecated libraries, use PDO instead.

```
$db = new PDO($dsn); //$dsn is the database connection strings. Depends on your DB.
                     //it can be as simple as "odbc:CONN_NAME"
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tablename"); 
//be sure to sanitize $tablename! use a whitelist filter, not escapes!
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //fetch as associative array
if($rows){
    //check if there are actual rows!
    $first_row = reset($rows); //Resets the internal pointer, return the first elem.

    $header_str = '<th>' . implode('</th><th>', array_keys($first_row)) . '</th>';
    $table_body_rows = array();
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $table_body_rows[] = '<td>' . 
                                implode('</td><td>', $row) . 
                             '</td>';
    }
    $body_str = '<tr>' . implode('</tr><tr>', $table_body_rows) . '</tr>';
    $tbl = "<table><thead><tr>$header_str</tr></thead><tbody>$body_str</tbody></table>";
} else {
    //something went wrong
}
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you load entire result set into associative array, consuming 2 times more RAM than you should. Then, you build entire HTML table with the rows *again* in RAM, consuming 3-4 times more RAM than you should, instead of echoing the values right away. And I am not even talking about the fact you're adding imploded array_keys($first_row) repeatedly in the foreach cycle (probably a typo, you should implode $row instead). Voting down, sorry.

Comment: 1. Every PHP array is an associative array, (it's basically a map, key=>value, and there is not much difference using numbers or strings as keys) 2. echoing right away is bad because you're not separating logic with presentation. this snippet can be safely put in a function and reused anywhere, anytime, anyhow. If you echo straight away, you're mixing logic with presentation. To be honest, I would have built an array and delegated to something else the translation from array to html table. 3. thanks for the typo notice, my mistake.

Comment: To further explain: yes, my choice may be more RAM-intensive, but fetchAll is usually faster than cycled single fetch calls, and cycled echoes are slower than string building followed by a single echo. There's a tradeoff between memory and speed, as usual.

Answer (score -1):

`show tables` is probably what you need

```
echo "<table><tr>";
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<td> $row[0] </td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>"
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what im looking for. I have a table named "listmgmt_list", in that table I have several entries with different SQL queries in them (in one of the columns). So when I extract one of those queries, I want to run them. So far so good. But when I do run the query I get from my table, how can I print out a table which has all the columns and all the entries? Via PHP/HTML

Comment: ok, sorry, i misread the question.   You can get the columnnames by using `SHOW COLUMNS FROM my_table;` , then print them in a table between `<th>` tags.  Then query the content and print it between `<td>` tags.

Comment: Use rather `mysqli_` than `mysql_`

Comment: The use of mysql_ libraries is deprecated

Answer (score -1):

If you need to print a row with header (column names), you have to do it this way:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($result)<1) echo "Table is empty";
else
{
   $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   echo "<table>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<th>".join("</th><th>",array_keys($row))."</th>";
   echo "</tr>";

   while ($row)
   {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".join("</td><td>",$row)."</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
       $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   }

   echo "</table>";
}
```

This is just the basic concept. If your table has values which may contain HTML tags and other stuff, you'll need to apply htmlspecialchars() on all values of $row. This can be done with array_walk(). Furthermore you didn't mention what PHP version are you using and what MySQL API do you prefer. Some people suggested to use mysqli or PDO, that's up to you to rewrite the code according to your preferred API.

Comment: Don't suggest the use of deprecated libraries!

Comment: Better use deprecated libraries than suggesting nothing like you.